# Developer got Appium setup and running JUnit test on Android emulator using his MAC. Can't get the same setup and tests working on my Windows machine

Tags: appium

```
info: Welcome to Appium v0.13.0
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
   info  - socket.io started
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"WINDOWS
","browserName":"","app-package":"com.elation.edagio","device":"Android","app-ac
tivity":".LoginActivity","version":"4.2"}}
info: Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on t
he device
info: Creating new appium session 3ca2e670-9455-4702-9f62-e62adc5f421c
info: Starting android appium
debug: Using fast reset? false
info: Preparing device for session
info: Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on
the device
info: Checking whether adb is present
```

And that is where it stops everytime; no matter what capabilities or combinations we try. I've tried several emulators through Eclipse. Also tried a Genymotion emulator. We cannot figure out why this won't run on my Windows 8.1 machine. Any pointers would be very helpful.

When I stop Appium I get this trace in Eclipse from the JUnit test:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'ChopperLaptop', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: LoginTest$SwipeableWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at com.elation.edagio.tests.LoginTest$SwipeableWebDriver.<init>(LoginTest.java:70)
    at com.elation.edagio.tests.LoginTest.setUp(LoginTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 29 more

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.elation.edagio.tests.LoginTest.tearDown(LoginTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the whole lot for appium? It stops in weird point.

It looks like you have a problem with your adb. Check that adb is running and the device is connected.

try

```
adb devices
```

It should show your Android device (and it shouldn't be offline or anything like that).

If nothing shows, try:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

And then again try the adb devices.

The error in eclipse you see is purely because you stop appium server.

Comment: More digging showed that appium is intended to run on MAC and not on Windows so we gave up on getting it to work. But your answer is correct; that did cause the stop and we try the kill and start

Comment: appium runs on windows 7+ to remotely run tests vs android with API16+, for older API versions you need selendroid. as your first log ends with an adb lookup, i wounder if you have installed the android sdk and set the correct %PATH% and %ANDROID_HOME% variables